# Emacs native database for fast key/value access?

Tags: alists, data-structures, hash-tables

I would like to do a key -> value lookup for data that may not fit into memory *(or simply avoid the overhead of having to load it an keep it in memory)*.

Does Emacs natively support any kind of database that can be used for fast lookups (like a hashtable) without having to first load everything into memory?

---

As an alternative I could hash the value myself, split it into buckets - then load a JSON file associated with that bucket (for example), but this seems like a weak solution to something that might already exist.

Comment: What did you find on melpa?

Comment: I came across this very old [db](https://melpa.org/#/db) package on melpa.  Also, starting from [Emacs 29](https://blog.phundrak.com/emacs-29-what-can-we-expect/?ref=upstract.com), SQLite will be included so a k/v store could be built on top of that.

Comment: Querying an external database seems the most practical given the goal of eliminating Emacs overhead.

Comment: @g-gundam I wasn't aware of sqlite support, this could be made into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Soon... (maybe early 2023)

Starting from [version 29](https://blog.phundrak.com/emacs-29-what-can-we-expect/), native SQLite support will be included in Emacs.

A key/value store could be built on top of this.  There is already a library on MELPA called [db](https://melpa.org/#/db) which provides an API for key/value stores in Elisp.  Its default store uses JSON files, but it was designed so that different backing stores could be used.  For example, [db-pg](https://melpa.org/#/db-pg) provides a PostgreSQL-backed key/value store.  Perhaps a db-sqlite could be written.  It might be time to breathe life back into [db](https://github.com/nicferrier/emacs-db).